# How to pass default values to redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have build a redux form it's a user profile form where user can edit profile detail For that. I want to put initial Value that is available in backend after that they can edit them as well. But I tried the way doc says https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/examples/initializefromstate/ but It is not working at all.
I am getting initial value from api and storing it in redux store.

> EditFormPage.jsx

```
let  EditProfileForm =(props) => {


    const [image, setImage]  = useState(null);
    const {handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting, classes} = props;

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const getDroppedImage = (imageSrc) => {

        setImage(imageSrc);
    }

    const getCroppedImage = (imageUrl) =>{
        //props.getProfileImage(imageUrl);
        dispatch(uploadProfileImage(imageUrl));
    }

    const data = {
        profilePic : props.profileDetail.profilePic,
        name : 'Hell ow',
        dob : props.profileDetail.dateOfBirth,
        sex: props.profileDetail.gender,
        contact: props.profileDetail.phoneNumber,
        address: props.profileDetail.address
    }
    useEffect(() => {

        load(data);
    }, [data])

    return (
        <Grid container className={"container edit_profile"}>
            <Grid className="profile_menu global-padding" container>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <Grid
                            container
                            alignItems="center"
                            justify="flex-end"
                            className="profile_menu_list"
                            xs={12}
                        >
                            <Field
                                type="file"
                                name="profilePic"
                                component={EditDropZone}
                                image={image}
                                getDroppedImage={getDroppedImage}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid
                            container
                            alignItems="center"
                            justify="flex-end"
                            className="profile_menu_list"
                            xs={12}
                        >
                            <Field name="name" component={renderInputField} />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid
                            container
                            alignItems="center"
                            justify="flex-end"
                            className="profile_menu_list"
                            xs={12}
                        >
                            <Field
                                name="dob"
                                showTime={false}
                                component={renderDateTimePicker}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid
                            container
                            alignItems="center"
                            justify="flex-end"
                            className="profile_menu_list"
                            xs={12}
                        >

                            <Field style={{flexDirection: 'row'}} name="sex" component={renderRadioButton}>
                                <RadioButton value="male" label="male"/>Male
                                <RadioButton value="female" label="female"/>Female
                            </Field>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid
                            container
                            alignItems="center"
                            justify="flex-end"
                            className="profile_menu_list"
                            xs={12}
                        >
                            <Field name="contact" normalize={normalizePhone} component={renderInputField} />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid
                            container
                            alignItems="center"
                            justify="flex-end"
                            className="profile_menu_list"
                            xs={12}
                        >
                            <Field name="address" component={renderInputField} />
                        </Grid>
                        <div style={{paddingTop: '20px'}}>
                            <LoadingButton type={"submit"} title={'Save'}/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </Grid>
                <Grid xs={12}>
                    <ImageModal
                        getCroppedImage={getCroppedImage}
                        image={image}
                    />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    )


}

EditProfileForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'EditProfileForm',

    validate
})(EditProfileForm);
EditProfileForm = connect(
    state => ({
        initialValues: state.editProfileData.profileData
    }),{load: load }
)(EditProfileForm)

export default EditProfileForm;
```

Any help would be great I am stuck here.

Comment: If my memory doesn't let me down, there's a key `initialValues` where you can pass an object with default values. Here's the [explanation](https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/examples/initializefromstate/). In your case you should apply `initialValues` to to your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass `enableReinitialize: true` in the form.
Since you are passing values by the API calls, there would be some delay.
But Redux-form tried to show default value which is still undefined.
So, you would not be able to show default values from the API calls.
by enabling this option, when props are updated, your profile form will show those values as default.

```html
EditProfileForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'EditProfileForm',
    enableReinitialize: true, // need to set as True to reflect updated props.
    validate
})(EditProfileForm);
EditProfileForm = connect(
    state => ({
        initialValues: state.editProfileData.profileData
    }),{load: load }
)(EditProfileForm)
```

Comment: I believe every other part of the code works well. so that, my answer can work right.